# How to find $(w-w^4)$ and $(w^3-w^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

---

I did the first parts :

$$w= (\cos \pi + i sin \pi)^\frac{1}{5} \implies w^5 = \cos \pi + i \sin \pi=-1$$

---

$w=-1$ is a root so :

$w^5-1= (w+1) (w^4-w^3+w^2-w+1)=0$$

$$w^4-w^3+w^2-w=1$$

---

How to do the last part?

This is all I could do which is rewriting  it as:

$$(w-w^4)+(w^3-w^2)=1=\cos 2\pi + i sin 2\pi$$

Comment: $w^4=(\cos\frac\pi5+i\sin\frac\pi5)^4 = \cos\frac{4\pi}5+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{5}$.

Comment: @QuangHoang Got it :D thank you very much :D